# Adding image to Video but It was distorted

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-processing

I have a UIView (see Photo) and a video (see Video), I want to export that view to image (see "UIView to UIImage" code) and add to a video (see "Add UIImage to video" code).
But my result is not good (see Result).
Please help me this problem, thank you!

**Photo**

[image]

**Video**
[image]

**Result**
[image]

**UIView to UIImage**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**Add UIImage to video**

```
- (void)showImage:(UIImage*)img toCompostion:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition fromTime:(CGFloat)fromTime toTime:(CGFloat)toTime videoSize:(CGSize)size {
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *viLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:viLayer];

    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    viLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    // 1 - set up the overlay
    CALayer *imgLayer = [CALayer layer];

    [imgLayer setContents:(id)[img CGImage]];
    imgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, img.size.width, img.size.height); // Oxy: bottom left
    [imgLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    // 2 - set up the parent layer
    [parentLayer addSublayer:imgLayer];

    // the code for the opacity animation which then removes the image
    imgLayer.opacity = 0.0;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [animation setDuration:0.1]; //duration
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
    [animation setBeginTime:fromTime]; // time to show text
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [imgLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];


    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [animation setDuration:0.1]; //duration
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
    [animation setBeginTime:toTime]; // time to show text
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [imgLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity1"];
    ////

    // 3 - apply magic
    composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:viLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

}
```

********Update 1********
It's ok if I do this:
(1) change scale of UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions from 0.0 to 1.0.
(2) save image to file.
(3)Wait 0.01secs and read back that file.
I don't know why need to save to file????

Comment: What is the actual problem ? are u getting a blurred image or the image position not fits with screen.

Comment: the figure is not scaled, it changed from rectangle to parallelogram :(

Comment: Why do you need an image? If it is a simple red rectangle. You should draw it yourself so you can set antialiasing, rasterizing and other stuff.

Comment: I want to draw to a video, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Distortion of the image happens only on following cases ,

1. Image layer size is Lesser than actual height of the parent Layer.
2. The aspect ratio of the image not match with the aspect ratio of the layer.

In your code check the "parent layer " frame size and the "image Layer " frame

Comment: In your code check the "parent layer " frame size and the "image Layer " frame. you given (x,y) = (50,50).   followed by image width , height.   imgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, img.size.width, img.size.height);     change this to CGRectMake(50,img.size.height+10,ims.size.width,img.size.height)

Comment: Thank Rathna but your suggest make the rectangle out of screen!

Comment: try these . CGRectMake ( 50,0,img.size.width,img.size.height).... try increase the height of the video or decrease the height of the image .

Comment: remove imgLayer setMaskToBounds=YES. try.    print the log of the parentlayer frame size , img layer frame size , vi layer frame size

Comment: It's ok if I do this: (1) change scale of UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions from 0.0 to 1.0. (2) save image to file. (3)Wait 0.01secs and read back that file. I don't know why it works!!

Comment: aspect ratio of video and the image get matched when u change from 0.0 to 1.0... wait for 0.01 sec is for the time to get load the imag ecompletly

Comment: It not work if I don't save to file? Why need to save to file?